# how can i do auto arima for multiple products in R?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, forecast

i'm creating auto arima model in R for predict my demand. I do it for 1 product and its work. Im export in xlsx format, in columns:

- Sku(product),
- Date predict (next 3 months)
- Point forecast, low95% and high 95%.

My code is:

*ps: variable names in portuguese because im from brazil.*

```
bdvendas <- read.csv("Pedidos+PedidosItem.csv", header = T, sep = ";")

vendas <- bdvendas %>% 
  dplyr::select(dataPedido,SkuRaiz,quantidadeItemReal)

vendas$dataPedido <- dmy(vendas$dataPedido)

vendas <- subset(vendas, vendas$dataPedido > "2018-12-31")
vendas <- subset(vendas, vendas$SkuRaiz!="")
vendas <- na.omit(vendas)

teste <-  data.frame(as.yearmon(vendas$dataPedido))
teste <- cbind(vendas,teste)
names(teste)[1:length(teste)] <- c("dataPedido","SkuRaiz","Pedidos","MesPedido")

vendas <- teste %>% 
  group_by(MesPedido,SkuRaiz) %>% 
  summarise(Pedidos = sum(Pedidos))

analisesku <- vendas %>% 
  filter(SkuRaiz == 1081) ## <- HERE I SELECT MY PRODUCT

analisesku <- analisesku[-length(analisesku$Pedidos),]

ano_inicial <- as.numeric(format(analisesku$MesPedido,'%Y'))[1]
mes_inicial <- as.numeric(format(analisesku$MesPedido,'%m'))[1]

ano_final <- as.numeric(format(analisesku$MesPedido,'%Y'))[length(analisesku$MesPedido)]
mes_final <- as.numeric(format(analisesku$MesPedido,'%m'))[length(analisesku$MesPedido)]

tsbanco <- ts(analisesku$Pedidos, start = c(ano_inicial,mes_inicial), end = c(ano_final,mes_final), frequency = 12)
autoplot(tsbanco)

modelo <- auto.arima(tsbanco, stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE, trace = TRUE)
previsao <- forecast(modelo, h=2, level = c(95))
print(previsao)
autoplot(previsao)
accuracy(previsao)
output <- print(summary(previsao))
output <- cbind(analisesku$SkuRaiz[1],output)
names(output) <- c("SkuRaiz","pointForecast","low95","high95")
mesprevisao <- data.frame(seq(as.Date(Sys.Date()), by = "month", length = 3))
names(mesprevisao) <- "mesPrevisao"
output <- cbind(mesprevisao,output)

write.table(output, file = "previsao.csv", sep = ";", dec = ',', row.names = F, col.names = T)
```

Thats work good.

But, my problem is: i need to do that for multiple products (around 3000 products), automatically.

ps: each product have unique series. They are independent.

How can i do that? I need to use loop or something like that?

Comment: Use the fable package with the ARIMA function (which implements the same algorithm as auto.arima from the forecast package). It is designed to handle multiple time series and integrates with the tidyverse which you are already using.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide any data so I will simulate some data and demonstrate step by step how you can forecast multiple time series.

## Load forecast library

```
library(forecast)
```

## Lets simulate 5 time series from an ARIMA Model

```
bts <- ts(dplyr::tibble(AA = arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.5),
                                       n=100, mean = 12),
                        AB = arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.5),
                                       n=100, mean = 12),
                        AC = arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.5),
                                       n=100, mean = 11),
                        BA = arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.5),
                                       n=100, mean = 10),
                        BB = arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.5),
                                       n=100, mean = 14)), start = c(2000, 1),
          frequency = 12)
```

## Plot all ts

```
autoplot(bts)
```

## Fit the model to all ts

```
fit <- sapply(bts, FUN = auto.arima, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE,
              # auto.arima arguments
              max.p = 5,
              max.q = 5,
              max.P = 2,
              max.Q = 2 # other arguments passed to auto arima
              )
```

## Forecast all models

```
fc <- sapply(fit, FUN = forecast, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE,
             h = 12 # forecast horizon
             # other arguments passed to forecast
             )
```

#### This simple function will help us to get mean, lower or upper level forecast in the list

```
get_value <- function(x, type = c("mean", "lower", "upper"), 
                      level = c(80, 95)){
  if(type == "mean"){
    out <- x[["mean"]]
  }
  if(type == "lower"){
    if(level == 80){
      out <- x[["lower"]][,1]
    }
    if(level == 95){
      out <- x[["lower"]][,2]
    }
  }
  if(type == "upper"){
    if(level == 80){
      out <- x[["upper"]][,1]
    }
    if(level == 95){
      out <- x[["upper"]][,2]
    }
  }
  return(out)
}
```

## Get the mean forecast

```
point_forecast <- sapply(fc, FUN = get_value, simplify = TRUE, 
                         USE.NAMES = TRUE,
                         type = "mean")
```

## Get upper value with 95 % confidence interval

```
fc_upper_95 <- sapply(fc, FUN = get_value, simplify = TRUE, 
                         USE.NAMES = TRUE,
                         type = "upper", level = 95)
```

## Get upper value with 80 % confinence interval

```
fc_upper_80 <- sapply(fc, FUN = get_value, simplify = TRUE, 
                      USE.NAMES = TRUE,
                      type = "upper", level = 80)
```

#### Since you have many time series it is a good idea to fit models in parallel to use computing resources efficiently

```
library(parallel)

n_cores <- parallel::detectCores()-1 # number of cores in your machine -1 core

cl <- makeCluster(n_cores)

fit_par <- parallel::parSapply(cl, bts, FUN = auto.arima, 
                               simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE,
                               # auto.arima arguments
                               max.p = 5,
                               max.q = 5,
                               max.P = 2,
                               max.Q = 2)

fc_par <- parallel::parSapply(cl, fit_par, FUN = forecast, simplify = FALSE, 
                              USE.NAMES = TRUE,
                              h = 12
                              # other arguments passed to forecast
                              )

point_forecast <- parallel::parSapply(cl, fc_par, FUN = get_value, 
                                      simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE, 
                                      type = "mean")
```